# Python string list, cant format properly

Tags: python, pandas

calling a traffic api and getting data in the wrong format with python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# make sure to install these packages before running:
# pip install pandas
# pip install sodapy

import pandas as pd
from sodapy import Socrata

# Unauthenticated client only works with public data sets. Note 'None'
# in place of application token, and no username or password:
client = Socrata("data.pa.gov", None)

# Example authenticated client (needed for non-public datasets):
# client = Socrata(data.pa.gov,
#                  MyAppToken,
#                  userame="user@example.com",
#                  password="AFakePassword")

# First 2000 results, returned as JSON from API / converted to Python list of
# dictionaries by sodapy.
results = client.get("dc5b-gebx", limit=50000)

# Convert to pandas DataFrame
results_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(results)
```

results_df.latitude comes out as this

```
latitude
0   40 36:56.627
```

This is obviously not correct, assuming it's due to how the api call is handled?

There is another location_1 column, it has string data like this.

```
    location_1
    0   {'latitude': '40.6157', 'longitude': '-75.4621'}
    1   {'latitude': '40.4587', 'longitude': '-79.9985'}
    2   {'latitude': '39.9328', 'longitude': '-75.2891'}
    3   {'latitude': '40.4435', 'longitude': '-80.0046'}
    4   {'latitude': '40.5994', 'longitude': '-75.4703'}

I need the lat and lon as separate columns
```

SUper confused as to the best way, currently i get a weird out, i'm thinking of simple taknig the dataframe like this,

```
    list(df.location_1.values)
```

Then looping through the inner values,

```
    dict = {}
        n = 0    
        for x in list:
                n+=1
                append(x.strip())
```

Then taking it into a dataframe afterwards.

```
        crn arrival_tm  dispatch_tm crash_year  crash_month day_of_week time_of_day hour_of_day county  illumination    weather road_condition  collision_type  latitude    longitude   cons_zone_spd_lim   est_hrs_closed  location_1
    0   2016000001  0110    0109    2016    01  6   0108    01  39  Dark street lights  No adverse conditions   Dry Angle   40 36:56.627    75 27:43.540        1   {'latitude': '40.6157', 'longitude': '-75.4621'}
    1   2016000004  0148    0144    2016    01  6   0140    01  02  Dark street lights  No adverse conditions   Dry Hit fixed object    40 27:31.184    79 59:54.587            {'latitude': '40.4587', 'longitude': '-79.9985'}


df["location_1"] = df["location_1"].apply(lambda x : dict(eval(x)))
df2 = df['location_1'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Then using this to try and turn them into what i need, i get an error of,

```
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code objec
```

#### Updated with full amount of what's happening

Comment: Are the cells strings or dicts?

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML and React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df["location_1"] = df["location_1"].apply(lambda x : dict(eval(x)))
df2 = df['location_1'].apply(pd.Series)
```

df2 will have your lang and lat.
Then you can either merge or concat df2 to df

Comment: This returned, float has no attribute keys

Comment: To be able to help you better, please post your DF. What is the column name?

Comment: posted above now

Comment: See above corrected answer

Comment: TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
This error came about